# HTTP Error 500.0 - Internal Server Error, AspNetInitializationExceptionModule VS 2015

Tags: visual-studio

After running some NuGet Updates my project **will not run locally** throwing "HTTP Error 500.0 - Internal Server Error" and referencing Handler "AspNetInitializationExceptionModule"
**I'm using VS 2015, .NET Framework 4.6.1, Any CPU, IISExpress.**

The refered link suggests I look into the IIS Logs which are full of data but there seems to be no information for these eyes.

I Understand that 500.0 is the server shouting that something generic went wrong but frankly I don't know what to try next.

Any thoughts?
*Frustrated in New Hampshire.*

More info
adding a vanilla favicon.ico still resulted in 500.0 but now just at the root.

HTTP500: SERVER ERROR - The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.
(XHR): GET - http://localhost:3029/

Comment: It starting to look like something is wrong with 
http://localhost:3029/favicon.ico. File is there, must be damaged or screwed up in the project file. The time waste continues..

Answer (score 1):

Drilling into Eventviewer/Custom Views/Summary page events I found an ASP.NET 4.0.30319.0 Warning.
At the bottom of the warning detail it says
**System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssemblyHelper(String assemblyName, Boolean starDirective) Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.AI.Agent.Intercept' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

   http://localhost:3029/**

So my Nuget Update incorrectly updated Microsoft Application Insights.
Uninstalled it and now I'm back to earning a living.

It seems that when IIS knows it has an exception it should tell the browser.

Pat NH USA

Comment: Could you please tell what ApplicationInsights nuget package versions did you have before and after the update? Did you update only Intercept and not other packages?

Comment: Could you please also tell how did you uninstall package?.. I think that when nuget got updated it did not add binding redirect (or you rolled back changes to web.config). If you ever have this issue again you can check you need to check if you have correct binding redirect. E.g. when updating from 1.2.0 to 1.2.1 you would need: <dependentAssembly>. 
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.AI.Agent.Intercept" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.2.1.0" newVersion="1.2.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>